# Pass Dictionary as Value in Cobbler CLI --autoinstall-meta

Tags: automation, cobbler

I want to use `--autoinstall-meta` flag in Cobbler CLI to pass metadata to kickstart.

`cobbler system edit --name=<system-name> --autoinstall-meta="<the ks_meta>"`

The problem i'm facing is to pass dictionary as a value to a certain key.
Let's say i want my ks_meta to be `{a:{b:c}}` or even more complex `{a:{b:[c,d]}}`

I can't find the parser that `--autoinstall-meta` uses to parse the value or any example showing how to do that, the only examples I find include `string=string` values such: `--autoinstall-meta="a=b c=d"`

any help?

I have trying multiple options from common sense like

`cobbler system edit --name=<system-name> --autoinstall-meta="a=b:c"`

`cobbler system edit --name=<system-name> --autoinstall-meta="a=b:c;d:e"`

`cobbler system edit --name=<system-name> --autoinstall-meta="{a:{b:c}}"`

None worked, it always takes everything after the `"="` no matter what is it and pass it as a value.
Thank You!